# React router provides javascript object instead of original type on url address bar reload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router, react-router-dom

I am explining my problem with just the relevant code, as the full example is in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-tree-6qvu0) codesandbox link.

I am passing some props through a link to a component.
These props, have a firebase timestamp.
The props are passed correctly when the component is called through the link.

Link:

```
<Link to={{
    pathname:path, 
    state: {
        project
    },
}} key={project.id}>
<ProjectSummary project={project} deleteCallback={projectDelete}/>
</Link>
```

Route:

```
<Route
    path='/project/:id'
    render={({ location }: {location: Location<{project: IFirebaseProject}>})  => {
        const { state } = location;
        const returnedComponent = state ? <ProjectDetails project={state.project} /> : 
        <ProjectDetails project={undefined}/>;

        return returnedComponent;
    }}
/>
```

and received by the `ProjectList` component, like this:

```
<div>{moment(stateProject.createdAt.toDate()).calendar()}</div>
```

My problem is that when the component is called through the link, props are passed and everything works fine, but, when I re-enter in the url adress bar, as the access to the component is not through the link, I would expect that the Route's render returned an undefined project (check route:
`const returnedComponent = state ? <ProjectDetails project={state.project} /> : <ProjectDetails project={undefined}/>;`) but, it returns the last passed project, with the timestamp as a plain Javascript object instead of a Timestamp type. So I get the error:

```
TypeError: stateProject.createdAt.toDate is not a function
```

Because the `toDate()` function is not available in the plain Javascript object returned, it is the Timestamp firebase type. Seems that for this specific case, the router is keeping it as a plain js object, instead of the original Timestamp instance. I would expect the route to return always the proyect undefined if not called from the link, as the props are not passed in (supposedly), but its not the case on the reload from the url address bar.

Curiously, in the codesandbox project, it does not reproduce, it fetches the data (you will be able to see the `console.log('project fetched!!')` when the project received is undefined).

However thrown from the dev server it happens. Might have something to do.
Find the git url if you wish to clone and check: https://github.com/LuisMerinoP/my-app.git

Remember that to reproduce you just need to enter to the link, and then put the focus in the explorer url address bar en press enter.

I case this might be the expected behaviour, maybe there is a more elegant way to way to deal with this specific case instead of checking the type returned on the reload. I wonder if it can be known if it is being called from the address bar instead of the link.

I know I can check the type in my component and fix this, creating a new timeStamp in the component from the js object returned, but I do not expect this behaviour from the router and would like to understand what is happenning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: Non-Serializable State

> It returns the last passed project, with the timestamp as a plain Javascript object instead of a Timestamp type
>
> I do not expect this behaviour from the router and would like to understand what is happening.

What's going on is that the `state` is being serialized and then deserialized, which means it's being converted to a JSON string representation and back.  You will preserve any properties but the your methods.

The docs should probably be more explicit about this but [you should not store anything that is not serializable](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/621#issuecomment-423412806).  Under the hood React Router DOM uses the browser's History API and [those docs make it more clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState#parameters).

#### Suggestions

- `as` in typescript is an assertion.  It how you tell the compiler "use this type even though it's not really this type".  When you have something that really is the type then do not use `as`.  Instead apply a type to the variable: `const project: IFirebaseProject = {`
- Your `getProjectId` function to get an id from a URL is not necessary because React Router can do this already!  Use the `useParams` hook.
- Don't duplicate props in state.  You always want a "single source of truth".

#### Fetching Data

I played with your code a lot because at first I thought that you weren't loading the project at all when the page was accessed directly.  I later realized that you were but by then I'd already rewritten everything!

Every URL on your site needs to be able to load on its own regardless of how it was accessed so you need some mechanism to load the appropriate project data from just an `id`.  In order to minimize fetching you can store the projects in the state of the shared parent `App`, in a React context, or through a global state like Redux.  Firestore has some built-in caching mechanisms that I am not too familiar with.

Since right now you are using dummy placeholder data, you want to build a way to access the data that you can later replace your real way.  I am creating a hook `useProject` that takes the `id` and returns the project.  Later on just replace that hook with a better one!

```
import { IFirebaseProject } from "../types";
import { projects } from "./sample-data";

/**
 * hook to fetch a project by id
 * might initially return undefined and then resolve to a project
 * right now uses dummy data but can modify later
 */
const useProject_dummy = (id: string): IFirebaseProject | undefined => {
  return projects.find((project) => project.id === id);
};
```

```
import { IFirebaseProject } from "../types";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import db from "./db";

/**
 * has the same signature so can be used interchangeably
 */
const useProject_firebase = (id: string): IFirebaseProject | undefined => {
  const [project, setProject] = useState<IFirebaseProject | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    // TODO: needs a cleanup function
    const get = async () => {
      try {
        const doc = await db.collection("projects").doc(id).get();
        const data = doc.data();
        //is this this right type?  Might need to manipulate the object
        setProject(data as IFirebaseProject);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    get();
  }, [id]);

  return project;
};
```

You can separate the rendering of a single project page from the logic associated with getting a project from the URL.

```
const RenderProjectDetails = ({ project }: { project: IFirebaseProject }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container section project-details">
...
```

```
const ProjectDetailsScreen = () => {
  // get the id from the URL
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  // get the project from the hook
  const project = useProject(id ?? "");

  if (project) {
    return <RenderProjectDetails project={project} />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Loading project... </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/handling-dummy-data-79vby?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: So amazing how complete and helpfull this answer has been. Actually it took me quite a while to go throw it and be aware of all the new tricks that were provided. Thank you so much for your answer, not only explaining what was happening in my problem that was driving me nuts, but for providing all the appropiate approach to handle the specific sutiation, catching the data instead of passing the props through the link to the route. Hope I could vote this up a couple dozen times more.

Comment: Yes that is definitely possible!  Usually I use Redux to store my data entities.  I would use a Redux `useSelector` hook inside the `useProject` hook to look for existing data and only fetch if it doesn't already exist. Behind the scenes Redux uses React Contexts to make the data available everywhere.  I'm not too familiar with Firebase, honestly.  I know that there are packages for automatic Redux integration like `react-redux-firebase`.

Comment: There are some built-in caching capabilities in Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: thanks a lot!! I deleted the comments to try myself before asking :). I was thinking of exposing the projects array in the `useProjectList` hook, that with the use effect listener will maintain that array always updated. Then I may import that exposed array. Don't know if that is possible (expose hook data to the outer scope I mean) or makes if it makes any sense but I will check that out. Your useSelector proposal sounds very good. I was not aware of that :)

Comment: wow I was not aware fo the firebase offline features, catching the database to enable offline work, so cool!

Comment: As far as "the outer scope", basically you can expose data to the scope of a all descendants of a React Context Provider component: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html